# Populating a 2d Integer Array based on data in int array

Tags: java

I have an int array preliminaryAssignments = [6,7,7,7], whereby each index is a node paired with a different node. I.e, node 0 is paired with 6, nodes 1-4 paired with 7 
and a 2d array neighbors = [[5, 6], [5, 7, 8, 9], [5, 7, 9], [5, 7, 8, 9]] representing all possible node pairings for each index. I.e- node 0 could be paired either 5 or 5, node 1 could be paired with 5, 7, 8, 9, etc.

I want to make a 2d Integer Array "otherOptions" of each node's alternate options that they're not paired with. I.e [[5],[5,8,9],[5,9],[5,8,9]]

I am having trouble populating otherOptions. Here is some code I've been working on.

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> otherOptions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(n-1);
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
            otherOptions.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < n-1; x++ ) {
            for (int y = 0; y< k; y++) {
                if (neighbors.get(x).get(y) != preliminaryAssignment[x]) {
                    otherOptions.get(x).add(neighbors.get(x).get(y));
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help here?
Thanks

Comment: *I am having trouble populating otherOptions* - what problems? Also what is `k`?

Comment: k is the max amount of nodes each node could be paired with

Comment: Did you mean "nodes 1-3 paired with 7"? --- Did you mean "node 0 could be paired either 5 or 6"?

Comment: Your question text says that your data is in *arrays*, but your code indicates that they are is *lists*. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in *arrays*, like specified in the question, your code should be:

```
int[][] otherOptions = new int[neighbors.length][];
for (int nodeIdx = 0; nodeIdx < neighbors.length; nodeIdx++) {
    otherOptions[nodeIdx] = new int[neighbors[nodeIdx].length - 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < neighbors[nodeIdx].length; i++) {
        if (neighbors[nodeIdx][i] != preliminaryAssignments[nodeIdx]) {
            otherOptions[nodeIdx][j++] = neighbors[nodeIdx][i];
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
int[] preliminaryAssignments = {6, 7, 7, 7};
int[][] neighbors = {{5, 6}, {5, 7, 8, 9}, {5, 7, 9}, {5, 7, 8, 9}};
// code from above here
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(otherOptions));
```

*Output*

```
[[5], [5, 8, 9], [5, 9], [5, 8, 9]]
```

---

If the data is in *lists*, like used in the question code, your code should be:

```
List<List<Integer>> otherOptions = new ArrayList<>();
for (int nodeIdx = 0; nodeIdx < neighbors.size(); nodeIdx++) {
    List<Integer> others = new ArrayList<>(neighbors.get(nodeIdx));
    others.remove(preliminaryAssignments.get(nodeIdx));
    otherOptions.add(others);
}
```

*Test*

```
List<Integer> preliminaryAssignments = Arrays.asList(6, 7, 7, 7);
List<List<Integer>> neighbors = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(5, 6),
                                              Arrays.asList(5, 7, 8, 9),
                                              Arrays.asList(5, 7, 9),
                                              Arrays.asList(5, 7, 8, 9));
// code from above here
System.out.println(otherOptions);
```

*Output*

```
[[5], [5, 8, 9], [5, 9], [5, 8, 9]]
```

---

If the data is in lists of unknown type, i.e. `get(int)` may be slow, your code should be:

```
List<List<Integer>> otherOptions = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Integer> prelimIter = preliminaryAssignments.iterator();
for (Iterator<List<Integer>> neighborIter = neighbors.iterator(); neighborIter.hasNext(); ) {
    List<Integer> others = new ArrayList<>(neighborIter.next());
    others.remove(prelimIter.next());
    otherOptions.add(others);
}
```